# Why is PHPUnit creating the output "S" for a test that passes?

Tags: json, eclipse, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit  in Eclipse IDE and this is the output when running my unit test:

```
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.S.........

Time: 190 ms, Memory: 5.50Mb

OK (10 tests, 45 assertions)
```

The output has an `S` which suggests that a test is being skipped. However, there is no message "`Skipped: 1`".

According to the manual, the test output should look [like this](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests):

```
.S.........    
Time: 190 ms, Memory: 5.50Mb

1) UnitTest_Directory_Test::testBenthicCover
The MySQLi extension is not available.
/home/sb/DatabaseTest.php:9

OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!
OK (10 tests, 45 assertions, Skipped: 1)
```

Is the test actually passing, or is it being skipped?

Why do I not see `Skipped: 1`?

<sub>Environment: PHPUnit 3.7.28, Eclipse Java EE IDE, Version: Helios Service Release 2</sub>

---

I've logged the test results in json format for debugging:

```
    {"event":"suiteStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","tests":10}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testBenthicCover"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testBenthicCover","status":"pass","time":0.27545499801636,"trace":[],"message":"","output":"S"}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfMeasurementAverage"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfMeasurementAverage","status":"pass","time":0.17307710647583,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testEqualNumberOfSamplingUnitsPerSurveyParentToChild"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testEqualNumberOfSamplingUnitsPerSurveyParentToChild","status":"pass","time":0.0017728805541992,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfCountPerUnitArea"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfCountPerUnitArea","status":"pass","time":0.0038161277770996,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfFishCountPerUnitArea"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfFishCountPerUnitArea","status":"pass","time":0.0051858425140381,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfPercentCover"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfPercentCover","status":"pass","time":0.0044069290161133,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfGramsPerUnitArea"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfGramsPerUnitArea","status":"pass","time":0.0045709609985352,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfGramsPerUnitVolume"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfGramsPerUnitVolume","status":"pass","time":0.0045430660247803,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfTonsPerUnitAcreFromGramsPerUnitArea"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testCalculationOfTonsPerUnitAcreFromGramsPerUnitArea","status":"pass","time":0.0042028427124023,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
{"event":"testStart","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testParentEqualities"}
{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testParentEqualities","status":"pass","time":0.0016450881958008,"trace":[],"message":"","output":""}
```

Comment: what do you get when running PHPunit with the `-v` flag? (and also try it together with the `--strict` flag)

Comment: I usually run PHPunit with the following flags: "--log-json "${project_loc}/output/${selected_resource_path}.json" --verbose "${resource_loc}"". Isn't the --verbose flag the same as -v? I tried adding --strict but get the same result.

Comment: Try running PHPUnit without the json formatter but with --verbose so you can see which test is skipped

Comment: I tried running PHPUnit without the json formatter but with the --verbose argument, but get the same test result on the console: `PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.S.........

Time: 157 ms, Memory: 5.50Mb

OK (10 tests, 45 assertions)`. Based on the json file from before, I think the test that's skipped is shown in this line: `{"event":"test","suite":"UnitTest_Directory_Test","test":"UnitTest_Directory_Test::testBenthicCover","status":"pass","time":0.27545499801636,"trace":[],"message":"","output":"S"}`.

Comment: @diverdan,  This might be a bug with PHPUnit when you mix the flags `--verbose` with `--log-json`. Does running  `--verbose` without  `--log-json` solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the S and W in PHPUnit's test output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453481/whats-the-s-and-w-in-phpunits-test-output)

Comment: I'm running PHPUnit from the terminal using phpunit.phar and I'm getting back the expected result but also those JSON objects. Is there a way not to get them? perhaps a setting to disable them? Thanks