# What's the S and W in PHPUnit's test output?

Tags: php, phpunit

I recently updated the PHPUnit by Sebastian Bergmann and when I tried running the test cases, I got this as output:

```
...EEE.EEEEE.E.EE............EFFFE.F..FF.........SSSSSSSSSSSSSS  63 / 110 ( 57%)
SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS....W.W                 110 / 110 (100%)
```

According to the documentation, I could find that:

```
.   Success
E   Error
F   Failed
```

I am not sure what's `W` and `S` here. Can someone tell me what's that? If additional information helps, the `W` is in yellow colour and `S` is in blue colour.

Comment: Something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21267485

Comment: Let me have a look at it...

Comment: @PraveenKumar No, nothing related. Sorry.

Comment: I got it... Answered...

Answer (score 25):

According to the [Docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html):

```
.   Printed when the test succeeds.
F   Printed when an assertion fails while running the test method.
E   Printed when an error occurs while running the test method.
R   Printed when the test has been marked as risky (see Chapter 6).
S   Printed when the test has been skipped (see Chapter 7).
I   Printed when the test is marked as being incomplete or not yet implemented (see Chapter 7).
```

And according to the [Source Code](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.7/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php#L454):

```
public function addWarning(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, PHPUnit_Framework_Warning $e, $time)
{
    $this->writeProgressWithColor('fg-yellow, bold', 'W');
    $this->lastTestFailed = true;
}
```

The **yellow bold `W`** is for Warning. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Maybe PHPunit would be wise to add a LEGEND at the top of the output before tests start running...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.7/en/textui.html), `S` stands for **S**kipped tests (i.e., tests that are marked by an annotation meaning they should not be run).

Comment: Got the W from Source Code. `:D`

Answer (score 0):

S means skipped, see here: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#textui Unsure what W means, perhaps "warnings"?

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are describing all the params excep `W`. If you are using Laravel and you see this bold yellow `W`, there is a test which file name does not match the class name inside. You need to run all the tests in side using `--debug`. First place you see the `W` shows the problematic class:

```
phpunit tests/ --debug
```